# version table empty using phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm using phoneGap application. I created new app. Then drop and drag the CordovaLib.xcodeproj into smaple app. But when launch xcode it's showing empty in version field. Is it correct or i need to change? I have version empty in xcode like below picture. Is it correct?

[image]

Comment: can you please describe,how to create a project phonegap ios ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the version number is represented correctly in config.xml, it doesn't matter as much.

However, this doesn't mean it isn't without problem. Many Xcode services will error when attempting to perform various tasks, such as validating the app with Xcode's iTunes Connect integration.

Ideally, the version number in Xcode and config.xml should match. If they don't, fix it!

Comment: I have this line <widget id="com.example.app" version="1.0.0" inside config.xml. Is i need to put 1.0.0 to version?

Comment: @user2967559 Yes - that is the version that Cordova thinks the app should be, and so that is what should be in Xcode.

Comment: this is in build column not in version. can you check my edited code with image?